# Server does not recognize PHP stylesheet

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I am currently working with a Wordpress theme that uses a PHP file as the main stylesheet (style.php).
I guess this is because of the fact that you can do a lot of css styling through the CMS of the theme.

Now the problem is the fact that my server does not recognizes the php file as the main stylesheet, so the website is loaded without any styled elements.

Can somebody tell me how I can fix that? (through the use of an .htaccess file maybe?)

Comment: How are you including the stylesheet in the template's head tag?

Comment: Hi Zoltan!Thanks for your reply :) this is what the first lines look like:                                                     <?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
<?php require_once( '../../../wp-load.php' ); ?>
<?php $os = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); ?> So I guess that must be right?

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure that you add the correct "text/css" header to the top of the php page, in order for it to be parsed as CSS.

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Then you can include the php file as a css include:

Comment: Guys! Thanks a lot, but I found out what the problem was, namely that my CHMOD was set to 777, but my .htaccess file needed to be 775! That did the trick!